# Control individual linewidths in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

Is it possible to widen the linewidth for sepcific columns and rows in a seaborn heatmap?

For example, can this heatmap

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, linewidths=1.0)
```

be transformed into something like this:

[image]

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076488/single-row-or-column-heat-map-in-python) was also asked later today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, but may be a lot of work. A possible solution might look like shown below. It involves plotting 6 different heatmaps and adjusting the spacings such that it looks okish. One then also needs to synchronize the colorscaling and manually set the colorbar.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

data = np.random.rand(10, 12)

asp = data.shape[0]/float(data.shape[1])
figw = 8
figh = figw*asp

cmap = plt.cm.copper
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin= data.min(), vmax= data.max())

gridspec_kw = {"height_ratios":[9,1], "width_ratios" : [4,5,3]}
heatmapkws = dict(square=False, cbar=False, cmap = cmap, linewidths=1.0, vmin= data.min(), vmax= data.max() ) 
tickskw =  dict(xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)

left = 0.07; right=0.87
bottom = 0.1; top = 0.9
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2, figsize=(figw, figh), gridspec_kw=gridspec_kw)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=left, right=right,bottom=bottom, top=top, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1*asp )
sns.heatmap(data[:9,0:4], ax=axes[0,0], xticklabels=False, yticklabels=True, **heatmapkws)
sns.heatmap(data[:9,4:9], ax=axes[0,1], xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, **heatmapkws)
sns.heatmap(data[:9,9:12], ax=axes[0,2],xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, **heatmapkws)

sns.heatmap(data[9:,:4], ax=axes[1,0], xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, **heatmapkws)
sns.heatmap(data[9:,4:9], ax=axes[1,1], xticklabels=True, yticklabels=False, **heatmapkws)
sns.heatmap(data[9:,9:12], ax=axes[1,2], xticklabels=True, yticklabels=False,**heatmapkws)

axes[1,0].set_yticklabels([9])
axes[1,1].set_xticklabels([4,5,6,7,8])
axes[1,2].set_xticklabels([9,10,11])

cax = fig.add_axes([0.9,0.1,0.03,0.8])
sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
fig.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer (though the code could be cleaner by using a `for` loop instead of copy-pasting calls to `sns.heatmap`.)

Comment: @mwaskom Yes the code may become cleaner, but potentially less understandable, given that the loop would need to control 4 different numpy indizes as well as x- and y-ticklabel toggling. Now, the ticklabels might be set externally of the loop, but that makes it harder to get the default state of the tick being in the middle of the pixel. That's why I decided against it. I think it's easier for anyone to  adapt the above solution into a loop, than understanding a loop. What is most anoying is anyways the adaption to the correct aspect ratio - which by the way isn't perfect here.

Comment: Thanks again Ernes. You are a big help.I can work with that!